# Discussion Forum throwing error when trying to view

Tags: forum, discussion

I just installed the Discussion forum module on a local site and have been going through the docs setting it up. When I try to view it on the front-end I get the error below..any ideas?

Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Template::parse_date_variables() in /Users/mlohrman/Sites/synergetics/public_html/synerg/expressionengine/modules/forum/mod.forum_core.php on line 8298

EE v 2.7.2
Discussion Forum v 3.1.15

Comment: I have the same problem. is there a way to get the previous version without paying for support?

Comment: Yes, email EllisLab from the email address associated with your account, and they can provide previous versions that you might be authorized to receive.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up paying EllisLab for support only to find out the newest version of Discussion Forum only works with EE v2.8+. They provided the next version down which is working fine.